# Can we unit test ApplicationInstaller in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, nunit

Well i am doing unit testing. Now i am new to unit testing. I am using nunit and rhino mock with mvc3 framework. Should i unit test ApplicationInstaller.cs ? please suggest me some recommanded readings for nunit testing.

```
public void Install(Castle.Windsor.IWindsorContainer container, Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Configuration.IConfigurationStore store)
{
    container.Register(
        AllTypes.FromAssemblyContaining<IEmployeeModelAssembler>()
        .Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith("Assembler"))
        .WithService.DefaultInterfaces());

    container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(x => x.LogUsing(LoggerImplementation.Log4net).WithConfig("log4net.config"));

    container.Register(
        // All controllers
        AllTypes.FromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).BasedOn<IController>().LifestyleTransient(),
        //
        Component.For<IControllerFactory>().ImplementedBy<IoCControllerFactory>(),
        Component.For<ICookieManager>().ImplementedBy<CookieManager>().LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Transient),
        Component.For<IJsonSerializer>().ImplementedBy<JsonSerializer>(),
        Component.For<ILoanActionsUtility>().ImplementedBy<LoanActionsUtility>(),
        // Default D.I. container
        Component.For<IWindsorContainer>().Instance(container));

    // Register AES web services
    container.Install(new AESServicesBootstrapper.ApplicationInstaller());

}

#endregion

/// <summary>
/// Creates a WCF client for web services passing the token of the authenticated user from the cookie.
/// This method only creates the client / channel, it does not configure the connection settings,
/// those have to be defined by named endpoints on the web.config
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
/// <param name="endPointConfiguration">name of the endpoint on the web.config</param>
/// <returns></returns>
```

}

Comment: Can you make your title and question agree? The questions "can we..." and "should we..." are different (although, of course, if the answer to the first is "no", the second question is moot)

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, there isn't much value in testing the code above. It's basically configuration without any decision making so your tests could only ensure that the application is configured the way you want it. This is basically duplication of your code above.

If there were logic happening in your installer, then you might want to have some tests around it. If things started to get out of hand with lots of logic, then you're looking into the realm of removing that code into another class and not even including it in your installer code.

You might have some luck on [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/66480/when-is-it-appropriate-to-not-unit-test) with these types of questions.